# A k-linear exact functor between which preserves indecomposables is faithful

Tags: category-theory, modules

I'm having trouble to show the following statement.

Let $A,B$ be k-algebras, and mod$(A)$ be finite generated $A$-modules, same for mod$(B)$. Let
$$F: \text{mod}(A) \to \text{mod}(B)$$
be a k-linear, exact functor and preserves indecomposables (namely, if $V\in \text{mod}(A)$ is indecomposable, then $F(V)$ is indecomposable as a $B$-module).

Claim: $F$ is faithful.

Comment: If you know something to the effect that all finitely-generated $A$-modules are completely decomposable then it comes down to the fact that $F$ is exact and preserves non-zero-ness of objects.

Comment: @ZhenLin As an alternative to assuming complete decomposability, you can use the fact that every nonzero finitely generated module has a maximal submodule, which is always true (assuming AC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zhen Lin points out in a comment, it is enough to show that, as well as being exact,  $F$ takes nonzero modules to nonzero modules, since if $\alpha:X\to Y$ is a nonzero map then (because $F$ is exact) $F(\operatorname{im}(\alpha))=\operatorname{im}(F(\alpha))$, and so
$$F(\alpha)=0\Leftrightarrow\operatorname{im}(F(\alpha))=0\Leftrightarrow
F(\operatorname{im}(\alpha))=0\Leftrightarrow\operatorname{im}(\alpha)=0
\Leftrightarrow\alpha=0,$$
and so $F$ is faithful.

To prove that $F$ takes nonzero modules to nonzero modules, you can use the fact that (by Zorn's Lemma) every nonzero finitely generated module $M$ has a maximal submodule, and hence a simple quotient $S$. Simple modules are indecomposable, so (using exactness of $F$ again) $F(M)$ has an indecomposable (and in particular nonzero) quotient $F(S)$. So $F(M)$ is nonzero.